# How to use plotly-dash and jupyter-plotly-dash on google-colab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, plotly-dash

So i've come across a module that might be wonderful if i could use as i wished, which is [jupyter-plotly-dash](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-plotly-dash/)

The problem is that i want to run it on google colaboratory as there is where i store my data.
But running the example provided in the link above it says `localhost refused to connect.` So i presume that we might want to change the default `url` to the one that might work on `google colab`. How to do that?